# Export Keyframes as Text (After Effects)

Tags: after-effects, keyframes

Given a list of keyframes, is it possible to download them or export them to be used elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.  When you select keyframes in After Effects, you can paste them into any text editor and modify them.

Below is a shaped with some position keyframes applied, copied, then pasted into TextEdit on the Mac:

[image]

You can tweak them in any editor, then return them back into After Effects, so long as you don't break the formatting.